# How can I open a folder with an application

Tags: windows, powershell, directory

I have an application that can "serialize" its state as a folder with images. This folder is called, e.g., `C:\Temp\MyProject.ImageExplorer` and the FileSystem consists of :

```
C:\Temp\MyProject.ImageExplorer\Pic1.jpeg
C:\Temp\MyProject.ImageExplorer\Pic2.jpeg
...
```

1. Can I Configure Windows Explorer in a way, that a Double Click on a folder with my .ImageExplorer "extension" does not open the folder but starts my ImageExplorer.exe with the folder name as command line argument?
2. Can I modify the C# .Net OpenFile Selector in a way to open these "Folders" including the Filter by extension ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it but might have issues since the file type is a folder. What I would do is basically make it a uncompressed .ZIP file, You can change the extension to what ever you want so you can associate it with your application like `.IZP`

You can make your application setup a registry key that associates `.IZP` with your application and pass the path to the file in as parameter to `program.exe path/to/izp/that/user/opened`

You might just have to adjust the program to handle reading a container rather than a folder.

Comment: Thanks for Suggestion. Your ideal is nice, but I need to interact with Files in the folder with file.copy, file.open etc. and have to avoid extracting to a Temp folder

Comment: Because there is no compression the file essentially just becomes a container like a folder. I was sure you didn't need to extract it but cannot find a good example. Have you thought about using a flat file db like sqllite to store the binary image data.